# Android Set Custom Preference Divider Color

Tags: android, android-preferences

I am making an app that uses Preferences for a settings menu.  I have code for the different objects in the menu, but the dividers are a pale white color.  I would like to make it a darker color (like black) so that it would be easier to see.  My current code is as follows:

preferences.xml:

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <PreferenceCategory
        android:title="Appearance" />

    <ListPreference
        android:key="color_scheme"
        android:title="Color Scheme"
        android:summary="Change the color scheme of the app"
        android:dialogTitle="Color Scheme"
        android:entries="@array/colors"
        android:entryValues="@array/colors"
        android:defaultValue="Default (Blue Gray)" />

    <PreferenceCategory
        android:title="Other" />

    <Preference
        android:key="@string/preference_reset"
        android:title="Reset Values"
        android:summary="Reset all values to their default value" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

styles.xml:

```
<style name="PreferenceStyle">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/text_color_dark</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/text_color_gray</item>
    <item name="android:listSeparatorTextViewStyle">@style/ListSeperatorColor</item>
</style>

<style name="ListSeperatorColor" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:background">@color/text_color_dark</item>
</style>
```

And finally:

```
setTheme(R.style.PreferenceStyle);
```

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score 5):

Just add the following to your `PreferenceStyle` and remove the listSeparatorTextViewStyle

```
<item name="android:listDivider">@color/text_color_dark</item>
<item name="android:dividerHeight">1dp</item>
```